# How do I resolve the error "Expression must evaluate to a node-set" when checking for the existence of a node?

Tags: .net, xml, xpath

I'm attempting to check for the existence of a node using the following .NET code:

```
xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode(
        String.Format("//ErrorTable/ProjectName/text()='{0}'", projectName));
```

This always raises:

> XPathException: Expression must evaluate to a node-set.

Why am I getting this error and how can I resolve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The expression given evaluates to a boolean, not a node-set. I assume you want to check whether the ProjectName equals the parametrized text. In this case you need to write

```
//ErrorTable/ProjectName[text()='{0}']
```

This gives you a list of all nodes (a nodeset) matching the given condition. This list may be empty, in which case the C#-Expression in your sample will return null.

As an afterthought: You **can** use the original xpath expression, but not with SelectSingleNode, but with Evaluate, like this:

```
(bool)xmlDocument.CreateNavigator().Evaluate(String.Format("//ErrorTable/ProjectName/text()='{0}'", projectName));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Node node = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode(String.Format("//ErrorTable/ProjectName = '{0}'", projectName));

if (node != null) {
    // and so on
}
```

Edit: silly error

Answer (score 1):

The XPath expression contained a subtle error. It should have been:

```
xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode(String.Format("//ErrorTable/ProjectName[text()='{0}']", projectName));
```

The previous expression was evaluating to a boolean, which explains the exception error. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you came to this conclusion with the help of my links quoted above?

Comment: One of your links had the square bracket notation which I hadn't thought of using.