# XPath find all matches C# XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xpath, xmldocument

I am trying to figure out how to find all matches of string in a `XmlDocument`.

```
XmlNodeList results 
      = document.SelectNodes("Products/Product/fn:matches(.,'" + SearchWord + "')");
```

Im trying to compare the `innerText` of Product.

The above example don't work though, but I guess my way of using XPath functions are very wrong.

Comment: What string are you trying to find a match on ...? give an example please

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157044/how-do-i-resolve-the-error-expression-must-evaluate-to-a-node-set-when-checkin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Evaluate this XPath 1.0 expression** (did you know `matches()` is an XPath 2.0 function and isn't supported in .NET):

```
Products/Product/descendant::*[contains(text(), 'YourSearchWord')]
```

This selects all elements that have a text-node-child that contains the string `'YourSearchWord'` and that are descendents of a `Product` element that is a child of a `Products` element that is a child of the current (context) node.

**You can compose the XPath expression with**:

```
string.Format("Products/Product/descendant::*[contains(text(), '{0}')]", 
              SearchWord )
```

However, if `SearchWord` is obtained from user input, it is recommended never to include it in a skeletal string as above, so that XPath injection will be avoided.

If this is the case, the recommended method is to have a precompiled XPath expression in which the user input will be referenced as a variable and the value of this variable will be consumed from the XPath evaluation context.

**More details how to prevent an XPath injection can be found in this answer**:

**https://stackoverflow.com/a/6393690/36305**

Comment: That explains why using matches would never work for me. I will try your code example later today and it looks like it is what  I need! I will keep you posted in a couple of hours. Thank you so much

Comment: Hi Dimitre, I just tested the XPath, but it fails with 'Products/Product/descendant::*[contains(text(), 'ra']' has an invalid token. Do I need to make any changes to it so that works in C# XmlDocument context?

Comment: @user750508: Yes, a closing bracket is missing -- should be: `/Product/descendant::*[contains(text(), 'ra')]`

Comment: @user750508: I fixed the typo in my answer -- try it now.

Comment: Here's a +1 for dealing with the xPath injection issue.

Comment: @james.garriss, Yes, this issue becomes even more important with the standard <xsl:evaluate> XSLT 3.0 instruction.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you have  the following xml

```
<Names>
    <Name>
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
        <LastName>Smith</LastName>
    </Name>
    <Name>
        <FirstName>James</FirstName>
        <LastName>White</LastName>
    </Name>
</Names>
```

To get all  nodes use XPath expression /Names/Name. The first slash means that the  node must be a root node. SelectNodes method returns collection XmlNodeList which will contain the  nodes. To get value of sub node  you can simply index XmlNode with the node name: xmlNode["FirstName"].InnerText.

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(myXmlString); // suppose that myXmlString contains "<Names>...</Names>"

XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Names/Name");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
  string firstName = xn["FirstName"].InnerText;
  string lastName = xn["LastName"].InnerText;
  Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} {1}", firstName, lastName);
}
```

The output is:

Name: John Smith
Name: James White

use this as an example / starting point. thanks

Comment: Is there no way of doing it directly in the SelectNodes call?

Comment: What I am trying to do is basically get all products that matches the search query, but I do not want to look through all products. I want XPath to take care of it for me

Comment: +1. While using XPath to do everything is fun to achieve, you may be better of doing simple parts with XPath and other filtering with code as DJ suggested. I.e. original question contains "XPath injection" bug (similar to "SQL injection") i.e. if SearchWord contains double quote your XPath will fall apart.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: The way to avoid XPath injection and still construct and evaluate a single XPath expression is to have a precompiled XPath expression in which the user input will be referenced as a variable and the value of this variable will be consumed from the XPath evaluation context.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use the following:

`"Products/Product/[.='" + SearchWord + "']"`

or use functions such as `contains()`, `starts-with()`, or `normalize-space()` (trims and replaces consecutive white space with one space)

`"Products/Product/[contains(normalize-space(.), '" + SearchWord + "')]"`

Answer (score 0):

From the answer to [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157044/how-do-i-resolve-the-error-expression-must-evaluate-to-a-node-set-when-checkin):

> The expression given evaluates to a boolean, not a node-set. I assume
>   you want to check whether the ProjectName equals the parametrized
>   text. In this case you need to write
>
> ```
> //ErrorTable/ProjectName[text()='{0}']
> ```
>
> This gives you a list of all nodes (a nodeset) matching the given
>   condition. This list may be empty, in which case the C#-Expression in
>   your sample will return null.
>
> As an afterthought: You **can** use the original xpath expression, but
>   not with SelectSingleNode, but with Evaluate, like this:
>
> ```
> (bool)xmlDocument.CreateNavigator().Evaluate(String.Format("//ErrorTable/ProjectName/text()='{0}'", projectName));
> ```